# Is is possible to use the Web Authenitcation API with SSH keys?

Tags: ssh, webauthn

It looks like the current [Client to Authenticator Protocol (CTAP)](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-ps-20190130/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-ps-20190130.html) is really geared towards physical authenticators. Has there been any attempt at having software authenticators, such as SSH keys or GPG keyring or Gnome Keyring?

Answer (score -1):

Web Authentication API can be used only for registration and authentication and cannot be used for other purposes.

Where as the Security keys such as provided by Yubico and other companies, it depends upon what they provide such PIV/Smart Card, OpenPGP, OATH-HOTP/OATH-TOTP and Yubico OTP. You can manually configure your key to store ssh keys, GPG private keys, sign your git commits and more. [For more info please have a look](https://paulstamatiou.com/getting-started-with-security-keys/)

One last thing please see the reply by senior certification engineer about such questions [Yuri answer](https://medium.com/@GPalem/the-authenticator-is-it-useful-only-to-authenticate-or-can-it-be-used-for-more-general-purposes-43e00cea521c)

Software authenticator yes [krypton](https://krypt.co/)